# Why am I getting a "Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Y' when Y has an index signature?

Tags: typescript

```
type JSONValue =  string | {[x:string]:string}

function foo(p:JSONValue){
    console.log(p.aaaa);
}
```

the compiler says:

Property 'aaaa' does not exist on type 'JSONValue'.
Property 'aaaa' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

but this compiles:

```
type JSONValue =  {[x:string]:string}

function foo(p:JSONValue){
    console.log(p.aaaa);
}
```

why? how to fix?

Comment: `type JSONValue =  string | {[x:string]:string}` means that a `JSONValue` is allowed to be (among other possibilities) a string, right? So, if `foo` is called and `p` is a `string`, then what should `p.aaaa` mean?

Comment: check [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the line that triggers the error, `p` is known to be a `JSONValue`, which could be either a string or an object with a `[x:string]:string` index signature. If it were a string, then indeed it wouldn't have an `aaaa` property. That is essentially what the error is telling you.

For example, in the following the first `console.log` call won't generate an error because both `string` and `{[x:string]:string}` have the property `length`. Only the second log call will have the error:

```js
type JSONValue = string | { [x: string]: string }

function foo(p: JSONValue) {
    console.log(p.length)
    console.log(p.aaaa)
}
```

## solution: [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)

Clearly you want to access the property `aaaa` from `p` *ONLY IF* `p` is a `{[x:string]:string}`, not if it is a `string`, right?. So put that logic in your code! Like this:

```js
function foo(p: JSONValue) {
    if (typeof p === 'string') {
        // Typescript knows p has type string within this block
    } else {
        // Typescript knows p is not a string, and thus
        // by process of elimination must be a
        // { [x: string]: string } within this block
        console.log(p.aaaa)
    }
}
```

or like this:

```js
function foo(p: JSONValue) {
    if (typeof p === 'object') {
        console.log(p.aaaa)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is because when you're console logging, the compiler doesn't know if 'p' is a dictionary or a string. If it knew that it wasn't a string then it would compile correctly. The reason for this is because a string doesn't have the property 'aaaa'.

The way you would do this is:

```
type JSONValue =  string | {[x:string]:string}
function foo(p:JSONValue){
    if (typeof p != "string") {
        console.log(p.aaaa);
    }
}
```